# Calculate the days between two dates in UTC format in CSV file on linux

Tags: linux, csv, date

I have CSV file with 2 fields of dates and I want to calculate the number of days between each pair of dates and add a new field to the file.

the date are in UTC format: *2011-04-05 21:13:50.597 UTC*

Although I can get the answer for specific dates with this syntax:

```
let DIFF=`date -d "2011-04-05 21:13:50.597 UTC" +%s`-`date -d "2011-04-05 21:44:36.257 UTC" +%s`| echo $DIFF`
```

I didn't get how to calculate it for a file.

When I tried with brackets (Sorry for not using the Code format. there are ` in the syntax):

```
date -d $(awk -F, '{print$6}' sof10.csv) +"%s"
```

I got this error:

```
> date: extra operand ‘21:13:50.597’ Try 'date --help' for more information.
```

It's look like he didn't read it as a date but as a text,

When I tried with dashes:

```
 date -d "awk -F, '{print$6}' sof10.csv" +"%s"
```

the error was:

```
date: invalid date ‘awk -F, '{print}' sof10.csv’
```

Although if I write an actual date:

```
date -d "2011-04-05 21:44:36.257 UTC" +"%s"
```

it's ok and I get a number.

Every time I tried to read the date from the file, I got an error saying it didn't recognize the text as a date. I tried to cut the field, make a loop and several more attempts but each time I received the same error of the syntax or a separate error for each line (that the text is not recognized as a date)

```
cat sof10nc2.csv | while read line; do $(date -d $(echo $line | awk -F, '{print$6}')); done

Try 'date --help' for more information.
date: extra operand ‘UTC’
Try 'date --help' for more information.
date: extra operand ‘UTC’
Try 'date --help' for more information.
date: extra operand ‘UTC’
Try 'date --help' for more information.
date: extra operand ‘UTC’
Try 'date --help' for more information.
date: extra operand ‘UTC’
Try 'date --help' for more information.
date: extra operand ‘UTC’
Try 'date --help' for more information.
date: extra operand ‘UTC’
Try 'date --help' for more information.
date: extra operand ‘UTC’
Try 'date --help' for more information.
date: extra operand ‘UTC’
Try 'date --help' for more information.
```

The question as mentioned is what is the syntax for a CSV file that will calculate for each row the difference between the dates (and add it as an additional field)

Tnx

(Although there are many questions on the topic of dates and the calculation of differences, I did not find a reference to the syntax for calculation for each line of a file)

Here is few lines from the file:

```
Credit Memo No,title,sun,dep.,year,date1,order,sort,date2
4500233821,Sales Cloud - Enterprise Edition,24,2,4,2018-11-29 12:15:06.353 UTC,4500233821,7,2018-11-29 12:21:04.237 UTC
4500245641,Sales Cloud - Enterprise Edition,36,2,4,2018-11-29 12:15:06.353 UTC,4500245641,2,2018-11-29 12:21:18.113 UTC
4500242807,Sales Cloud - Enterprise Edition,0,2,1,2018-11-29 12:55:03.097 UTC,4500242807,1,2018-11-29 12:59:42.697 UTC
4500233852,Sales Cloud - Enterprise Edition,6,2,1,2018-11-29 12:55:03.097 UTC,4500233852,2,2018-11-29 13:05:22.943 UTC
4500234511,Sales Cloud - Enterprise Edition,36,0,0,2018-11-29 13:09:25.697 UTC,4500234511,,
4500242786,Sales Cloud - Enterprise Edition,30.6,2,1,2018-11-29 13:17:48.977 UTC,4500242786,1,2018-11-29 13:18:56.643 UTC
4500242786,Sales Cloud - Enterprise Edition,30.6,2,1,2018-11-29 13:17:48.977 UTC,4500242786,2,2018-11-29 13:24:55.31 UTC
4500253356,Sales Cloud - Enterprise Edition,6,1,1,2018-11-29 13:28:45.723 UTC,4500253356,2,2018-11-29 13:52:13.413 UTC
```

Comment: Please add a couple of lines of your input file to your question ...

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `awk` command, but I think the issue here is that `"2011-04-05 21:44:36.257 UTC"` must be passed as a single argument to `date`.


Your `awk` command is effectively executing `date -d "2011-04-05" "21:13:50.597" "UTC"` (this produces the error message that you posted)

Comment: @tink, I added an images. hope It will help.

Comment: Umm .. no. Images are no good. Do you expect people to type all that?

Comment: @tink, I didn't find the option for upload files.

Answer (score 0):

The differences between your columns are always much less than a day.

You can use [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/) (version >= 6.0) and run

```
mlr --csv filter '!is_null($date2)' then put '$delta_seconds=(strptime($date2,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f UTC"))-(strptime($date1,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f UTC"))' input.csv
```

to get

| Credit Memo No | title | sun | dep. | year | date1 | order | sort | date2 | delta_seconds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4500233821 | Sales Cloud - Enterprise Edition | 24 | 2 | 4 | 2018-11-29 12:15:06.353 UTC | 4500233821 | 7 | 2018-11-29 12:21:04.237 UTC | 357.8840000629425 |
| 4500245641 | Sales Cloud - Enterprise Edition | 36 | 2 | 4 | 2018-11-29 12:15:06.353 UTC | 4500245641 | 2 | 2018-11-29 12:21:18.113 UTC | 371.75999999046326 |
| 4500242807 | Sales Cloud - Enterprise Edition | 0 | 2 | 1 | 2018-11-29 12:55:03.097 UTC | 4500242807 | 1 | 2018-11-29 12:59:42.697 UTC | 279.60000014305115 |
| 4500233852 | Sales Cloud - Enterprise Edition | 6 | 2 | 1 | 2018-11-29 12:55:03.097 UTC | 4500233852 | 2 | 2018-11-29 13:05:22.943 UTC | 619.8460001945496 |
| 4500242786 | Sales Cloud - Enterprise Edition | 30.6 | 2 | 1 | 2018-11-29 13:17:48.977 UTC | 4500242786 | 1 | 2018-11-29 13:18:56.643 UTC | 67.66600012779236 |
| 4500242786 | Sales Cloud - Enterprise Edition | 30.6 | 2 | 1 | 2018-11-29 13:17:48.977 UTC | 4500242786 | 2 | 2018-11-29 13:24:55.31 UTC | 426.33300018310547 |
| 4500253356 | Sales Cloud - Enterprise Edition | 6 | 1 | 1 | 2018-11-29 13:28:45.723 UTC | 4500253356 | 2 | 2018-11-29 13:52:13.413 UTC | 1407.6899998188019 |

Some notes:

- `filter` to remove the rows in which `date2` is null;
- `put` to have difference. You need to specify the input format that is `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f`.

The output you have is in seconds.